# Module reference passed in call to module method

Tags: perl

I have a perl script called `fetch.pl` and a module called `My_Util.pm`.

**My_Util.pm**

```
package My_Util;

sub get_header
{
    my $msg = shift;
    return " ===== $msg ===== ";
}

1; # Perl modules must return a true value when loaded.
```

**fetch.pl**

```
use My_Util;

print_and_log(My_Util->get_header("foo"));
print_and_log("blah");

sub print_and_log
{
    my $message = shift;
    print("$message\n");
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
===== foo =====
blah
```

**Actual Output:**

```
===== My_Util =====
blah
```

Edit: Fixed syntax errors

Comment: `use My_Util.pm;` is a syntax error.

Comment: Your `MyUtil.pm` file is missing a `package` declaration and a return value.

Comment: Is your `My_Util.pm`( meant to be) a class, or not?  The problem is that the code you show can't run so it's not clear what's really happening.

Comment: Fixed the syntax errors (package declaration, import, and return code).  `My_Util.pm` is intended to be a collection of helpers.

Comment: If that package isn't meant to be(come) a class I'd suggest to _not_ use the `->` in order to call subs from it, but rather `My_Util::func` (or export the name `func` in the module and import it in the caller if you wish to be able to use the unqualified name).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `->get_header` syntax is that for a method call. A method call passes the invocant (i.e. the object or class name) as an implicit first argument.

So, assuming we have

```
package MyUtil;
sub foo {}
```

somewhere, the call

```
MyUtil->foo(1, 2, 3)
```

ends up doing `MyUtil::foo("MyUtil", 1, 2, 3)`.

Of course you can call

```
MyUtil::foo(1, 2, 3)
```

directly without passing any implicit arguments.

See also [`perldoc perlobj`](https://perldoc.pl/perlobj#Method-Invocation).

Another difference is that the `::` version does a normal function call, whereas the `->` version does a method call, which also follows inheritance, i.e. with `MyUtil->foo` there need not be a `MyUtil::foo` sub at all if `MyUtil` inherits from a class that provides a `foo` method.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that with the syntax `MyUtil->get_header()`, you are calling `get_header()` as a class method. That call gets converted to `MyUtil::get_handler('MyUtil', 'foo')` and you need to take account of that extra argument that is passed to your subroutine.

```
sub get_header {
  my $class = shift; # Get class name
  my ($msg) = @_;    # Get message

  return " ===== $msg ===== ";
}
```

If you don't intend for `get_header()` to be a class method, then don't call it as a class method. If you call it as `MyUtil::get_header('foo')`, then your existing module code will work fine.

Alternatively, you could "export" your subroutine from your module into the calling package. You can do this by adding the following two lines into your package:

```
use Exporter;
our @EXPORT = qw[get_header];
```

Then, from your main program, you will be able to call the exported subroutine without mentioning its package name at all.

```
get_header('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the call to `My_Util->get_header()` implicitly passes a reference to `My_Util` to `get_header()`, which isn't accounted for.

```
sub get_header
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $msg = shift;
    return " ===== $msg ===== ";
}
```

Comment: There's no reference being passed in `My_Util->get_header()`. The first parameter the method receives is a string containing "My_Util". That would usually be stored in a variable called `$class`, not `$self`.